# Is there an easy way of performing arithmetic on elements in a vector in R?

Tags: r, math, vector, counting

The input can be a vector of numbers or a string, and the output is the addition of the number 1 plus that element's position in the string of digits.

```
myFunciton(c(4,10))
[1] 5, 12
myFunction(1:10)
[1] 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
myfunction <- function(x) x + seq_along(x)

myfunction(c(4, 10))
#[1]  5 12
myfunction(1:10)
#[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Ronak! I really appreciate this!